# how to change the look and feel of a range-seek-bar?

Tags: android, seekbar

In my application i am using range-seek-bar library to obtain this functionality.
I want to change the look and feel of the the range progress bar displayed in this library.

I have tried changing the design in similar line with this code : 
[click here](http://javandroidevelop.blogspot.in/2012/09/cool-seekbar-custom-made-by-me.html)

But could not achieve anything as the default options of a seek bar are not present in the range-seek-bar.
I want the range seek bar to be styled as :

[image]

I am not able to figure out how to solve this issue... I am struggling with this from quite a few days.

Please help ! Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Have you tried with it images?

Comment: @user3676184 i am not getting where and how to place those images? the two thumbs i have replace with the images i want... but how do i chande the progress bar images??

Comment: Actually I have not implemented that but definitely there are 2 progress like primary and secondry.